# Help me understand what this log means

Tags: magento2.1.5, log, exception, error-log

I'm constantly getting this log in my var/debug.log file. I'm quite curious about this. I do not understand what it means.

> main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate: 
>   {"method":"GET","url":"http://127.0.0.1/m4/paym/redirect/?SID=rpgvdrc7v23j38i36i8a274ae1","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["vendor_payment_gateway_2","FPC"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []

I some how figured out that it has some connetions with my 
 model which is as below:

```
class Createorder extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel implements \Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface
{
    const CACHE_TAG = 'vendor_payment_gateway';
    protected $_cacheTag = 'vendor_payment_gateway';
    protected $_eventPrefix = 'vendor_payment_gateway';
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Vendor\Gateway\Model\ResourceModel\Createorder');
    }

    public function getIdentities()
    {
        return [self::CACHE_TAG . '_' . $this->getId()];
    }

    public function getDefaultValues()
    {
        $values = [];

        return $values;
    }
}
```

Being a magento developer I must understand what my logs are saying.